# excel vba code to filter columns containg any one of the words from a list

Tags: excel, vba, text, filtering

I am new to vba code and have been doing some research and am not sure how to approach this project.  I have a spreadsheet with 10 columns. I need to filter three of the columns.  The filter would be a list of six words.  For example, the three columns have groups of fruits in each cell.  I would want to only show the rowd which have cells that contain apple, oranges, grapes, pears, kiwi, or bananas.  If the cell does not contain any of these fruits then I would not want to see that row  I have found some snippets of code to filter with two words but not more than that.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: does your cells contains exact match? I mean exactly `apple` or they could contain some sentence with this word,  e.g. `I have too many aplles`?

Comment: It is a sentence which the words would be contained in.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've done my share of VBA coding and I try to avoid it when possible.  For this I would add a column with a formula and then use the built in filtering tools.  I wasn't sure whether each cell has a single fruit, or a list of fruits so I came up with formulas for both.
If each cell only contains a single fruit you might try something like this for a formula:

```
=OR(A2="apple", A2="oranges", A2="grapes", A2="pears", A2="kiwi", A2="bananas")
```

This will return true for "grapes", but not "a bunch of grapes".

If the fruit could be anywhere in the cell value you would need something more like this:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple", A2)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("oranges", A2)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("grapes", A2)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("pears", A2)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("kiwi", A2)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("bananas", A2)))
```

This will return true for "apple" and "a peck of apples".

This can be expanded to as many cell/string combinations as you wish.
Once you have the extra formula column just turn on the filter and done.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am going to try it in the morning.  My cells are sentences so the second solution should work.   I will let you know how it goes.  Thanks again!